# Python Pandas Error: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Date'

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying this (https://towardsdatascience.com/analyzing-world-stock-indices-performance-in-python-610df6a578f) on Jupyter Notebook with Python 3.9.13

The full code:

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import yfinance as yf

# Retrieving List of World Major Stock Indices from Yahoo! Finance
df_list = pd.read_html('https://finance.yahoo.com/world-indices/')
majorStockIdx = df_list[0]
majorStockIdx.head()


tickerData = yf.Ticker('^GSPC')
tickerDf1 = tickerData.history(period='1d', start='2010-1-1', end='2020-10-1')

stock_list = []
for s in majorStockIdx.Symbol: # iterate for every stock indices
    # Retrieve data from Yahoo! Finance
    tickerData = yf.Ticker(s)
    tickerDf1 = tickerData.history(period='1d', start='2010-1-1', end='2020-9-30')
    # Save historical data 
    tickerDf1['ticker'] = s # don't forget to specify the index
    stock_list.append(tickerDf1)
# Concatenate all data
msi = pd.concat(stock_list, axis = 0)

#  categorize each index by the region
region_idx={ 'US & Canada' : ['^GSPC', '^DJI', '^IXIC', '^RUT','^GSPTSE'],
  'Latin America' : ['^BVSP', '^MXX', '^IPSA'],
  'East Asia' : ['^N225', '^HSI', '000001.SS', '399001.SZ', '^TWII', '^KS11'],
  'ASEAN & Oceania' : ['^STI', '^JKSE', '^KLSE','^AXJO',  '^NZ50'],
  'South & West Asia' : ['^BSESN', '^TA125.TA'],
  'Europe' : ['^FTSE', '^GDAXI', '^FCHI', '^STOXX50E','^N100', '^BFX']
}

# make a new column for the region.

def getRegion(ticker):
    for k in region_idx.keys():
        if ticker in region_idx[k]:
            return k
msi['region']= msi.ticker.apply(lambda x: getRegion(x))

# Get the data for 4 Jan 2010
begRef = msi.loc[msi.Date == '2010-01-04']
def retBegin(ticker, val):
    start_val = begRef.loc[begRef.ticker == ticker, 'Close'].values[0]
    return (val/start_val - 1) * 100
    
msi['chBegin'] = msi.apply(lambda x: retBegin(x.ticker, x.Close), axis = 1)

# Transform the data to be ticker column-wise
chBegin = msi.groupby(['Date', 'ticker'])['chBegin'].first().unstack()
# Fill null values with the values on the row before
chBegin = chBegin.fillna(method='bfill')

fig, axes = plt.subplots(3,2, figsize=(12, 8),sharex=True)
pagoda = ["#965757", "#D67469", "#4E5A44", "#A1B482", '#EFE482', "#99BFCF"] # for coloring
for i, k in enumerate(region_idx.keys()):
# Iterate for each region
    ax = axes[int(i/2), int(i%2)]
    for j,t in enumerate(region_idx[k]):
        # Iterate and plot for each stock index in this region
        ax.plot(chBegin.index, chBegin[t], marker='', linewidth=1, color = pagoda[j])
        ax.legend([ticker[t] for t in region_idx[k]], loc='upper left', fontsize=7)
        ax.set_title(k, fontweight='bold')
fig.text(0.5,0, "Year", ha="center", va="center", fontweight ="bold")
fig.text(0,0.5, "Price Change/Return (%)", ha="center", va="center", rotation=90, fontweight ="bold")
fig.suptitle("Price Change/Return for Major Stock Indices based on 2010", fontweight ="bold",y=1.05, fontsize=14)
fig.tight_layout()
```

I am using Jupyter Notebook and the problem occurs at this section:

```
# Get the data for 4 Jan 2010
begRef = msi.loc[msi.date == '2010-01-04']
def retBegin(ticker, val):
    start_val = begRef.loc[begRef.ticker == ticker, 'Close'].values[0]
    return (val/start_val - 1) * 100
    
msi['chBegin'] = msi.apply(lambda x: retBegin(x.ticker, x.Close), axis = 1)

# Transform the data to be ticker column-wise
chBegin = msi.groupby(['Date', 'ticker'])['chBegin'].first().unstack()
# Fill null values with the values on the row before
chBegin = chBegin.fillna(method='bfill')
```

I get:

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Date'

How to fix this?

this is the full error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [14], in <cell line: 2>()
      1 # Get the data for 4 Jan 2010
----> 2 begRef = msi.loc[msi.Date == '2010-01-04']
      3 def retBegin(ticker, val):
      4     start_val = begRef.loc[begRef.ticker == ticker, 'Close'].values[0]

File ~/.julia/conda/3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py:5575, in NDFrame.__getattr__(self, name)
   5568 if (
   5569     name not in self._internal_names_set
   5570     and name not in self._metadata
   5571     and name not in self._accessors
   5572     and self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name)
   5573 ):
   5574     return self[name]
-> 5575 return object.__getattribute__(self, name)

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Date'
```

I hope someone here can help me out. Is the package incorrect? the code incorrect? or something else?

Comment: what is the output of `msi.head().to_dict()`?

Comment: You should add a MRE/sample and the full tracestack to your question, otherwise it's just guessing around.

Comment: Output of `msi.head().to_dict()`: `{'Open': {Timestamp('2010-01-04 00:00:00-0500', tz='America/New_York'): 1116.56005859375,`

Comment: @Timus I already add full code, use Jupyter Notebook for this.

Comment: `Date` is the index. So you could replace `msi.Date == ...` with `msi.index == ...`. Or add a `Date` column to `msi`: `msi['Date'] = msi.index` (or `df = df.reset_index(drop=False)` if you don't need the dates in the index).

Comment: I change into `msi.index == ...` then get this `index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0`

Comment: Where to begin: The index contains timestamps _with_ timezone, and you compare it to a string? Then: there's no guarantee that `begRef.loc[begRef.ticker == ticker, 'Close']` isn't empty, so `.values[0]` can fail ...?

Answer (score 0):

"Date" needs to be in lower case. Change this:

```
chBegin = msi.groupby(['Date', 'ticker'])['chBegin'].first().unstack()
```

To this:

```
chBegin = msi.groupby(['date', 'ticker'])['chBegin'].first().unstack()
```

Comment: Still not working `'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'date'
`

Answer (score 0):

The error says that your are trying to access a column named `date` but the dataframe doesn't have such column. Actually it has a columns named `Date` (note the uppercase `D`).

I think that the error is in the first line. Replace `msi.date` by `msi.Date`.

```py
begRef = msi.loc[msi.Date == '2010-01-04']
```

Comment: I changed it into Date and still not working.

Comment: The error message in the question says `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Date'`, i.e. no column `Date`?